# Interceptor for standard request structure in Angular 14

Tags: angular, typescript, web, interceptor

In my angular 14 project I have created an interceptor, that stadardizes the request for any kind of POST apis in a particular format.

Here is the snippet of my code :-

```
export class FormatRequestInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler) {
    const formattedRequest = this.formatRequest(request.body);
    const formattedHttpRequest = request.clone({
      body: formattedRequest,
    });
    return next.handle(formattedHttpRequest);
}

  private formatRequest(requestData: any): any {
    const formattedRequest = {
      status: 'status',
      payload: [requestData],
    };
    return formattedRequest;
  }
```

On providing this particular interceptor in my app.module.ts. This request structure gets applied through out the application.

Where the request body in sent inside the payload.

Now the catch is ----->

For certain post apis i am sending a FormData as a request in my application, I want to bypass the scenario where i am sending FormData as a request.

Modify the code for me where this particular scenario is handled.

Let me know, if you need any other information.

Comment: Well, the first thing that comes to my mind is checking if the `requestData` is an instance of `FormData` and/or checking if the `Content-Type` header is url-encoded..

Comment: @Eldar sounds great , and  return next.handle(request); for that scenario?

Comment: Yes, it's just a noop.

Comment: Thanks man, this seems to work now, here is the  if condition --> if (request.body instanceof FormData) {
      return next.handle(request);
    }  added to bypass it.